# Issue resolving Unity 2 container using NServiceBus 3 object builder

Tags: unity-container, nservicebus

I'm receiving the following error while using the NServiceBus 3.0.0 beta 2 pre-release object builder for Unity 2. As far as I have been able to trace, it appears to be a problem with the CommonObjectBuilder in the AutowireEnabledInjectionProperty builder.

Configuration for NSB is as follows:

```
public class NServiceBusContainerExtension : UnityContainerExtension
{
    protected override void Initialize()
    {
        var busConfig = NServiceBus.Configure.WithWeb()
            .Log4Net()
            .UnityBuilder(Container)
            .MsmqTransport()
                .IsTransactional(true)
                .PurgeOnStartup(false)
            .XmlSerializer()
            .UnicastBus();

        var bus = busConfig
                    .CreateBus()
                    .Start();

        Container.RegisterType<IPublisher, NServiceBusPublisher>(new InjectionConstructor(bus));
    }
}
```

Error:

```
[ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: typeToCreate]
   Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Utility.Guard.ArgumentNotNull(Object argumentValue, String argumentName) +55
   NServiceBus.ObjectBuilder.Unity.AutowireEnabledInjectionProperty.AddPolicies(Type typeToCreate, Type implementationType, String name, IPolicyList policies) +87
   Microsoft.Practices.Unity.UnityContainer.RegisterType(Type from, Type to, String name, LifetimeManager lifetimeManager, InjectionMember[] injectionMembers) +405
   Microsoft.Practices.Unity.InjectedMembers.ConfigureInjectionFor(Type serviceType, Type implementationType, String name, InjectionMember[] injectionMembers) +66
   Microsoft.Practices.Unity.InjectedMembers.ConfigureInjectionFor(Type typeToInject, InjectionMember[] injectionMembers) +22
   NServiceBus.ObjectBuilder.Unity.ConfigureComponentAdapter.ConfigureProperty(String name, Object value) +325
   NServiceBus.ObjectBuilder.Unity.UnityObjectBuilder.ConfigureProperty(Type concreteComponent, String property, Object value) +338
   NServiceBus.ObjectBuilder.Common.ComponentConfig.NServiceBus.ObjectBuilder.IComponentConfig.ConfigureProperty(String name, Object value) +120
   NServiceBus.ObjectBuilder.Common.ComponentConfig`1.NServiceBus.ObjectBuilder.IComponentConfig<T>.ConfigureProperty(Expression`1 property, Object value) +266
   NServiceBus.ObjectBuilder.Common.Config.ConfigureCommon.With(Configure config, IContainer container) +633
   NServiceBus.ConfigureUnityBuilder.UnityBuilder(Configure config, IUnityContainer container) +112
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like to have accepted [Udi's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/151350/udi-dahan) answer because, well, he's the man. However, I was never able to get the Unity 2 builder to work despite attempting to register every type that we needed.

After a week or so, I ended up going back to using the DefaultBuilder, passing in our prebuilt Unity container into a ServiceLocator, and registering the IServiceLocator as a singleton to NSB's default builder. It worked out quite well.

Answer (score 1):

You need to register all new types in the container before calling .CreateBus().

Comment: Udi, is this referring to the message types?

Comment: No, this is all handler types as well as anything you want injected into those handlers too.