# NServiceBus 3 with Unity 2 broken?

Tags: unity-container, nservicebus

I am using NuGet packages to reference the most recent version of NServiceBus (NServiceBus-CI 3.0.2034, NServiceBus.Unity-CI 3.0.2039), however I cannot get the UnityBuilder to work. The issue I am facing is similar to the one posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8651005/issue-resolving-unity-2-container-using-nservicebus-3-object-builder), however the accepted answer is not the solution to my problem.

```
var busConfig = Configure
            .WithWeb()
            .UnityBuilder()
            ...
```

or

```
var busConfig = Configure
            .WithWeb()
            .UnityBuilder(container)
            ...
```

results in

```
[ArgumentNullException]
Value cannot be null
Parameter name: typeToCreate
```

According to [this](http://tech.dir.groups.yahoo.com/group/nservicebus/message/11871) post the issue has been fixed, however it still seems to be broken.

Has anyone come across this and found a solution? Is there anything NServiceBus specific that I would need to register in the container before passing it to UnityBuilder?

I will keep researching this issue but it looks like I am hitting a wall at this point.

UPDATE

I have narrowed the problem down to the following line in ConfigureProperty method inside NServiceBus.ObjectBuilder.Unity.ConfigureComponentAdapter.cs

```
UnityContainerExtensions.Configure<InjectedMembers>(this.container).ConfigureInjectionFor((Type) this.concreteComponent, new InjectionMember[] { property });
```

It looks as if Unity container cannot resolve "InjectedMembers".

Answer (score 0):

I authored the other question that you referenced ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8651005/issue-resolving-unity-2-container-using-nservicebus-3-object-builder)), but I didn't accept Udi's answer at the time since it never really worked.

In short, I dropped the Unity2 Builder, went with the DefaultBuilder, and injected an IServiceLocator. The only type I registered with NServiceBus was the IServiceLocator as a UnityServiceLocator singleton, so NServiceBus didn't need to handle building up a Unity2 container.

Answer (score 0):

We have fixed a few issues in the unity builder lately. Can you guys give build 2064 a try and see if that helps?

http://teamcity.codebetter.com/viewType.html?tab=buildTypeStatusDiv&buildTypeId=bt459